# pandas pivot to calculate difference between max date and second to max date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, aggregate

I have a situation where I need to pivot the data in order to fetch the most recent and next to recent entry basis the date field. My data frame looks like:

```
State   country      Date             confirmed deaths  recover
  A         C     1/22/20             1         0       0
  A         C     1/23/20             1         0       0
  A         C     1/24/20             15        0       0
  A         C     1/25/20             39        0       0
  B         C     1/26/20             60        0       0
  B         C     1/27/20             70        0       0
  B         C     1/28/20            106        0       0
  B         C     1/29/20            152        2       0
  B         C     1/30/20            200        2       0
```

and the output I want should be like this:
So new the columns confirmed, deaths and recover should fetch the values basis the Max(Date) which is 1/25/20 for State A and 1/30/20 for State B
and newcases , newdeaths, newrecover should be the difference of the Max date values - second to max date values.

```
For example for state A new cases = 39-15= 24, newdeaths = 0-0=0 , newrecover = 0-0=0
```

**39 cases were at the max date and 24 cases were at the second to the max date as I need to get the daily change. This should be dynamic as it needs to be fetched daily**

```
State   country   confirmed deaths  recover      newcases     newdeaths    newrecover
  A        C           39       0        0       24           0             0
  B        C           200      2        0       48           2             0
```

Comment: For State B Column B, should newdeaths be 0, since `2-2=0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_values` by date ascending and `groupby` Date and extract last value in each group.Join this another groupby date that subtracts the secnd last value from the very last value in each group.

**Chained solution**

```
 df.groupby('State').tail(1).drop(columns=['Date']).merge(df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True).groupby('State')\
[['confirmed', 'deaths', 'recover']].apply(lambda s:(s.iloc[-1].sub(s.iloc[-2])))\
    .reset_index().rename(columns={'confirmed':'newcases','deaths':\
            'newdeaths','recover':'newrecover'}), how='left', on='State')
```

**Step by Step Solution**

```
g=df.groupby('State').tail(1).drop(columns=['Date'])

g1=df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True).groupby('State')\
[['confirmed', 'deaths', 'recover']].apply(lambda s:(s.iloc[-1].sub(s.iloc[-2])))\
    .reset_index().rename(columns={'confirmed':'newcases','deaths':\
            'newdeaths','recover':'newrecover'})


newdf=g.merge(g1, how='left', on='State')


   State country  confirmed  deaths  recover  newcases  newdeaths  newrecover
0     A       C         39       0        0        24          0           0
1     B       C        200       2        0        48          0           0 

   newrecover  
0           0  
1           0
```

Comment: I don't need the date column as I mentioned in my output. How to get rid of that? The output should be aggregated as I showed above.

Comment: Much faster solution @Django0602

Answer (score 1):

One method is to create a mask `m` with the `idxmax` to return a series of the max index of the `date`. Then, you can create a groupby object `gb` as a base that filters for `m` by passing it to `.loc` (rows that contain the max date per group) and using `.append` to `m-1` (rows that contain the second highest date per group). This `groupby` object base can then be used with `.diff()` on the relevant columns (e.g. `df['new cases'] = gb['confirmed'].diff()`).

```
m = df.reset_index().groupby(['State', 'country'])['index'].idxmax()
gb = df.loc[m].append(df.loc[m-1]).sort_index().groupby('State')
df['newcases'] = gb['confirmed'].diff()
df['newdeaths'] = gb['deaths'].diff()
df['newrecover'] = gb['recover'].diff()
df = df.dropna().drop('Date', axis=1)
df
```

output:

```
    State   country     confirmed   deaths  recover newcases    newdeaths   newrecover
3   A       C           39          0       0       24.0        0.0         0.0
8   B       C           200         2       0       48.0        0.0         0.0
```

Comment: I don't need the date column as I mentioned in my output. How to get rid of that?

Comment: @Django0602 see revised answer. You can drop a column with `.drop('Date', axis=1)` so the full second to last line of code is now `df = df.dropna().drop('Date', axis=1)`

Comment: TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' , I am getting this error

Comment: I just ran the above code, and it works perfectly. Did you paste `.drop('Date', axis=1)` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I did. At the same location as you have mentioned.

Comment: @Django0602 it should work, can you copy and paste the full error message or send me the line of code where you had the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218391/discussion-between-david-erickson-and-django0602).